# Finding the sys call table in memory 64-bit on 4.x.x Kernel

Tags: c, linux, memory, linux-kernel

I'm trying to write a simple kernel module to find the sys_call_table in Linux and am having some trouble. I found a basic guide for 32-bit Linux here: https://memset.wordpress.com/2011/03/18/syscall-hijacking-dynamically-obtain-syscall-table-address-kernel-2-6-x-2/. I tried to adapt it to a modern 64-bit kernel and am having some trouble. My code is here:

```
#include<linux/init.h>
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/errno.h>
#include<linux/types.h>
#include<linux/unistd.h>
#include<asm/current.h>
#include<linux/sched.h>
#include<linux/syscalls.h>
#include<linux/utsname.h>
//#include<asm/system.h>
#include<linux/slab.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

#define START_MEM   PAGE_OFFSET
#define END_MEM     ULLONG_MAX

unsigned long long *syscall_table;

unsigned long long **find(void) {
  unsigned long long **sctable;
  unsigned long long int i = START_MEM;
  while ( i < END_MEM) {
      sctable = (unsigned long long **)i;
      if ( sctable[__NR_close] == (unsigned long long *) sys_close) {
          printk(KERN_WARNING "------%p---------\n", (unsigned long long *) sys_close);
          return &sctable[0];
      }
      i += sizeof(void *);
  }
  return NULL;
}


static int __init init_load(void) {
  syscall_table = (unsigned long long *) find();
  if (syscall_table != NULL) {
    printk(KERN_WARNING "syscall table found at %p\n", syscall_table);
  }
  else {
    printk(KERN_WARNING "syscall table not found!");

  }
  return 0;
}

static void __exit exit_unload(void) {
  return;
}

module_init(init_load);
module_exit(exit_unload);
```

I compile the code using a simple makefile, no warnings or notices come up and here is what is printed (after insmod-ing):

```
$ dmesg
<snip>
[39592.352209] ------ffffffff8120a2a0---------
[39592.352214] syscall table found at ffff880001a001c0
</snip>
```

So all seems well right? But then I check out where the sys_call_table is by running:

```
punk@punk-vbox:~/dev/m-dev/rootkit-examples$ sudo cat /boot/System.map-4.4.0-36-generic | grep sys_call_table
ffffffff81a001c0 R sys_call_table
ffffffff81a01500 R ia32_sys_call_table
```

..meaning that my code seemingly gets the location of the sys_call_table totally wrong. So ffff880001a001c0 instead of ffffffff81a001c0.

I'm not entirely sure where to start debugging this. Am I doing something obviously wrong here? What would be a good first step to debugging this on my own? I'm fairly new to writing kernel modules and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Because you found a different place that was not sys_call_table, that also had the address of sys_close.

Comment: so a place in memory that just happens to have the exact right offset for __NR_CLOSE? It seems unlikely or am I missing something @immibis? It seemed to me like I may be dereferencing a pointer somewhere incorrectly?

Comment: Yes. You found another place in memory that happens to have sys_close at the offset __NR_close.

Comment: hm ok, any idea on fixes? Is this just not the right way to do it perhaps?

Comment: The right way to access the syscall table from a module is to not. If you were supposed to be accessing the syscall table from a module, it'd be exported, and it isn't. The right way to access the syscall table from non-module kernel code is just to access it normally like any other variable.

Comment: I just test your code with a hijack program(hijack-2.c) in [this link](https://memset.wordpress.com/2010/12/03/syscall-hijacking-kernel-2-6-systems/), and it worked. I think maybe your result is right. Maybe concerned about the security issue, the address in System.map is not right. At least, it' not worked in that hijack program.

Answer (score 1):

Your kernel may have enabled x32 compat.

1. There are two `sys_call_table`s in this kind of kernel. `compat_sys_call_table(ia23_sys_call_table)` for 32-bit and `sys_call_table` for 64-bit. And they use the same `sys_close`.
2. You may find `sys_close` in `compat_sys_call_table`, but `__NR_close` is different between 32-bit `unistd.h` and 64-bit `unistd.h`. You may be using 64-bit `__NR_close`, so you cannot get `compat_sys_call_table` nor `sys_call_table` correctly.

You can check my code, [ASyScallHookFrame](https://github.com/ne2der/ASyScallHookFrame), it works fine on Android kernel 3.10.