# exchange function in system call table in x86

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, system-calls, rootkit

i am trying to redefine an systemcall for sys_open and to track user behaviour with that.
I use a Linux Kernel 4.13.0-041300.
This is my code so far

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/syscalls.h>

MODULE_LICENSE ("GPL");

//this is where the original sys_open call position will be saved
asmlinkage long (*original_open)(const char __user *filename, int flags, umode_t mode);

unsigned long **sys_call_table;
//this is to track how often my replaced function was called...
static int zeug = 0;

//this is my open function that i want to be replaced in the sys_call_table
asmlinkage long replaced_open(const char __user *filename, int flags, umode_t mode)
{
    printk ("replaced wurde aufgerufen...\n");
    zeug++;
    return original_open(filename, flags, mode);
}

static void enable_page_protection(void)
{
    unsigned long value;
    asm volatile("mov %%cr0, %0" : "=r" (value));

    if((value & 0x00010000))
        return;

    asm volatile("mov %0, %%cr0" : : "r" (value | 0x00010000));
}

static void disable_page_protection(void)
{
    unsigned long value;
    asm volatile("mov %%cr0, %0" : "=r" (value));

    if(!(value & 0x00010000))
        return;

    asm volatile("mov %0, %%cr0" : : "r" (value & ~0x00010000));
}

//the function to get the system_call_table
static unsigned long **aquire_sys_call_table(void)
{
    unsigned long int offset = PAGE_OFFSET;
    unsigned long **sct;

    while (offset < ULLONG_MAX) {
        sct = (unsigned long **)offset;

        if (sct[__NR_close] == (unsigned long *) sys_close)
            return sct;

        offset += sizeof(void *);
    }

    return NULL;
}

static int __init minit (void)
{
    printk ("minit: startet...\n");

    if(!(sys_call_table = aquire_sys_call_table()))
            return -1;

    printk ("minit: sys_call_table ersetzt...\n");

    disable_page_protection(); 
    {
        //here i print the function name of the current function in sys_call_table
        printk ("minit: eintrag vor ersetzen:%pF\n", sys_call_table[__NR_open]);

        //here i store the real sys_open function and change to my func
        original_open =(void * )xchg(&sys_call_table[__NR_open],(unsigned long *)replaced_open);

}
    enable_page_protection();
    return 0;
}

static void mexit (void)
{
    printk ("mexit gestartet.\n");
    printk ("Open was called %d times...\n",zeug);
    if(!sys_call_table) return;

    //here i print the stored function again
    printk ("bei exit:%pF\n", sys_call_table[__NR_open]);

    disable_page_protection();
    {
            //change back to original sys_open function
            xchg(&sys_call_table[__NR_open], (unsigned long *)original_open);
    }
    printk ("nach zurücksetzen:%pF\n", sys_call_table[__NR_open]);
    enable_page_protection();
}

module_init(minit);
module_exit(mexit);
```

My plan:
After insmod this module to kernel, every systemcall of sys_open will be "redirected" to my function replaced_open. This function will count its calls and then call the original open function.

After rmmod of my module the original system_call open will be used again.

It seems, that the replacing works. So after insmmod I get the result replaced_open+0x0/0x40 [kroot].
That means, the original function sys_open was replaced to my replaced_open right?
and after removing my module I get the message SyS_open+0x0/0x20.

So it seems like replacing works.

My problem is: I don't see any printed messages from my replaced_open function. Also it seems that counting doesn't work.

It feels like the function wasn't replaced properly.

Do you have any help for me?

Comment: You probably should look into using [Linux Security Module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Security_Modules) hooks.  It was designed for doing exactly this, although for security purposes such as adding the additional checks to system calls that SELinux does.  Another thing you need to address: kernel system calls need to be multithread-safe.  Your increment `zeug++;` isn't atomic - it's actually "read value, add 1 to value, save value".  That will just cause incorrect counts in your code, but for something critical like `inode` reference counts it can cause serious problems.

Comment: Are you successfully finding the syscall table? That seems like the most likely to fail. Have you looked at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39502198/finding-the-sys-call-table-in-memory-64-bit-on-4-x-x-kernel

Comment: Maybe you should double-check, that you indeed found the syscall-table, for example by checking for `sys_close` _and_ `sys_fork` or the like.

Comment: when i run printk ("bei exit:%pF\n", sys_call_table[__NR_open]) i get SyS_open+0x0/0x20
as result. so it should be right i think. I get the same result when I run this before changing anything.

Comment: sys_fork and sys_open and so on are unknown. i can only check the sct with sys_close.

Comment: Your code works for me here, should be your sct to find the wrong, you can print the pointer address of the sct, compare with the correct sys_call_table on the kernel. Can you use kallsyms_lookup_name("sys_call_table")?